# Console Application C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Как задать минимально возможный размер окна консоли, меньше которого пользователь не сможет её уменьшить?! Спасибо за ответ ;)

Comment: У меня уменьшается до 12x1 символов. И то 12 наверно можно получить из системных настроек, разделив минимальную ширину окна на размер символа.

Answer (score 4):

Самое хорошее и дружественное к пользователю решение — при старте проверить размер консоли, и выдать ошибку. Возможно, предложить пользователю, чтобы программа поменяла размер консоли на удобный ей. (Если размеры поменяются в процессе работы программы, можно следить за изменениями в фоне или при каждом выводе на неё, например, и переспрашивать.)

Менять настройки пользователя без его на то согласия — хулиганское поведение, просто не делайте так. Если программа меняет без спроса *мои* настройки, я первым делом удаляю её, а потом ищу, где бы оставить злобный отзыв.

Comment: Но ведь Console.WindowWidth не трогает системные настройки, которые используются при открытии нового консольного окна, только для текущего. А человеку нужно сделать чтобы пользователь не мог уменьшать текущее консольное окно меньше минимального размера, например таблицу выводит, которая рушится при изменении размера.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это тоже не то, что нужно...

Comment: @ГеннадийП: Во-первых, консольное приложение может быть запущено в уже существующей консоли, в которой пользователь выставил свои, удобные ему размеры. Во-вторых, пользователь настраивает консоль под себя, и это его решение, в каком размере он хочет видеть консоль. Особенно если он сознательно уменьшил этот размер. Программа не должна игнорировать явно высказанное желание пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вам стоит вставить бесконечный цикл в Ваш метод Main, который будет отслеживать текущий размер окна консоли и в зависимости от размера предпринимать действия: если ширина или высота окна консоли стала меньше допустимой, возможно, тогда уже можно будет вызывать метод Console.SetWindowSize, чтобы установить минимально допустимые размеры окна консоли.

Comment: Правильней будет не в сам метод Main, а параллельным потоком.

Comment: @ГеннадийП может быть сформулируете отдельным ответом?

Answer (score 0):

Ни в коем случае не претендую на то, что это абсолютно годный вариант, однако работает.
Но при попытке сменить размеры консоли появляются неприятные артефакты перерисовки.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            Task t = Task.Run(() => {
                while (true) {
                    if (Console.WindowWidth < 50 || Console.WindowHeight < 50) {
                        Console.SetWindowSize(50, 50);
                    }
                }
            });

            // Ваш код

            t.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почти правильный ответ. Обработка ширины и высоты должна быть независимой. И не хватает знаменитого Thread.Sleep.

Answer (score -2):

Посмотрите методы [Console.WindowWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.windowwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) и [Console.SetWindowSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Эти методы не решат проблему.

Comment: Это все не то! С помощью этого свойства и метода можно установить размеры консоли, но их в последующем пользователь может изменить...

Answer (score -2):

Как вариант:

```
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
            static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
            static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
            const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
            const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
            const UInt32 SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
            const UInt32 SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008;
            const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
            const UInt32 SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
            const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
            const UInt32 SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080;
            const UInt32 SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100;
            const UInt32 SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200;
            const UInt32 SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400;

            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
            static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                IntPtr ConsoleHandle = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
                const UInt32 WINDOW_FLAGS = SWP_SHOWWINDOW;

                 Task t = new Task( () => {
                    while (true)
                        SetWindowPos(ConsoleHandle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 100, 200, WINDOW_FLAGS);


                });
                t.Start();
            }
```